# Crop part of Visual Studio Control

Tags: wpf, winforms, visual-studio

Is it possible to say crop out the first 50-100 pixels of a visual studio control, so they are not rendered on the screen? For example you have a Internet Browser control and you want to crop out the address bar portion of the control so the user cannot touch it.

Comment: That control has options to remove the address bar.

Comment: Yes, but I am using a iMacros control that doesn't have that ability. Currently I have just been overlapping that portion of the control with a panel, but was wondering if there was a better solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "Visual Studio Control". I'm not aware of such a thing. Do you mean WPF control or Windows Forms control? I'm sure the two require a completely different answer.

Comment: I guess I mean, WPF control.

Answer (score 0):

If you are want to move the control out on the top set its margin property just to 0,-50,0,0 where -50 is the number of pixels you wish to move the control to the top. If it doesn't have a Margin property, you may try placing it inside of a container that does then set its margin property.